# XML shows up as plain text

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, safari

I retrieve XML from a external provider, and for debugging i usually view it from the browser. Unfortunately the case is that only Internet Explorer is able to render the data as XML. All other browser as Chrome, Safari, Firefox all render it as plain text for some reason.

Can anybody explain why this is the case?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that MSIE applies a style sheet and makes the nodes expandable/collapsable? That is just the way MSIE rolls and not the way other browsers work. XML is normally consumed by machines, not humans, so attempts to add styling and behavior interfer with communication with the most likely users of xml (i.e. other programs and applications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to(if you can):

- force the mimetype of the returning page to `text/xml`
- control the declaration of the xml to check if its correct
- control the DOCTYPE declaration if is correct

You would paste here your code/the returned XML to show what is wrong!

**ADDED LATER**

Infact if the XML is not well formacted (ex: theres not a good escape of the attribute's value on some elements) The browser show all as plain text. Try to validate the text using the [W3C XML Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)

Then as i said, in the very first point, the returning mimetype in the request can be wrong: i have an example of you could find in the header sometimes(wrong example):

```
 POST /path/to/the/service/ HTTP/1.1
 Host: www.example.com
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Length: length

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 ....
```

If you look at the `Content-Type` you will see `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8` that would be `Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8` but the only way to fix that is modify the source code of the webservice that response with xml file. 
To verify that you can, for example using Chrome press `<F12>`, choose Network and reload the page(pointing to the resource that you want to look at) and take a look to the Type's column.

Comment: Can you tell me how i can force the mimetype?
When i parse in IE it begins with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>`, so i assume this is not a problem. Theres not much i can paste here, since the output is just plain text in the other browsers.

Comment: if you have access to the server side you can search in the language documentation how to force it(ex in php add `header ("content-type: text/xml");` at the beginning). instead on firefox there is this plugin -> [link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/force-content-type/).

Comment: unfortunately i dont have such access, but i have accessed the system as a XML through Java and C# for 2years now, so i assume they are doing everything according to the "book". There must be something wrong with the browsers when parsing.

Comment: ok, is not possible that someone change something on the webservice (for upgrade/bug correction or something else)? 
Have you tried the firefox plugin that i linked? I will edit my response and add some explanation on what i think that happens.

Comment: New discovery. The sourcecode shows up as XML, but the content view is plain text. How can i make it show the actual XML in my view (@Firefox).

Comment: I just realised that the best solution as is right now is using `view-source:url` instead. Since the source code is correctly parsed. But only IE parses the output as XML without looking at the source.